# Amazon ec2-get-console-output returns "File not found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just set up a free instance of an Amazon ec2 server. I'm trying to figure out how to SSH into it. I downloaded the command line tools for ec2 and, following what was written at this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html#EC2_LaunchInstance_Linux :

```
.ec2$ ec2-get-console-output [instance id]
File not found: ''
.ec2$
```

Where `[instance id]` refers to the id amazon lists in the list of instances I have. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Edit: I might add it seems to be doing this for any binary I try to run from the command line tools... even if I call them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I specified the key and cert in my .bash_profile file:

> export EC2_HOME=~/.ec2
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin
>
> export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY='ls $EC2_HOME/key.pem'
>
> export EC2_CERT='ls $EC2_HOME/cert.pem'